# Sign up activity crashes when triggered using a button

Tags: android

I have created a login activity which is the launcher activity. My login page has two buttons Signin or Signup. Signup button triggers another activity named Main2Activity which is a tabbed activity but it keeps crashing. Any help would be appreciated. Here's Main2Activity :

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

  /**
   * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
   */
  private ViewPager mViewPager;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.signup);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    //Student Sign up button clicked
    Button StdSignUp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stdsignup);
    StdSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent HomePage = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(HomePage);
      }
    });

    //Teacher Sign up button clicked
    Button TSignUp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tsignup);
    TSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent HomePage = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(HomePage);
      }
    });


  }
  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
      return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }


  /**
   * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
   * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
   */
  public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
      super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
      switch (position)
      {
        case 0:
          StudentSignup ss = new StudentSignup();
          return ss;
        case 1:
          TeacherSignup ts = new TeacherSignup();
          return ts;
        default:
          return null;
      }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      // Show 3 total pages.
      return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
      switch (position) {
        case 0:
          return "Student Account";
        case 1:
          return "Teacher Account";
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the button that triggers the Main2Activity in the Login Acvivity's onCreate() method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

  });
  Button mEmailSignUpButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Signupbtn);
  mEmailSignUpButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent Signup = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
      startActivity(Signup);//this starts sign up page activity named main2activity
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: please paste logcat

Comment: post logcat here to better help

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your new Activity to `AndroidManifest.xml`. For example:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_main2_activity"/>
```